# Foreach loop in Powershell on the console

Tags: powershell

Very simple question here, I want to see how can we process a bunch of commands using foreach on the command line (not through a PS1 script).

For instance, I display the directory listing on the console, now I want to execute 2 commands per object.

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ $_}
```

This is ok, it shows the filename twice, but lets say I wanted to run 2 Write-Host commands for the same object, would that be possible on the console?

PS: I'm trying to achieve writing an output to 2 files using the out-file cmdlet, so I can read something and have 2 separate out-file calls per object

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can script in the console windows just as you would in a powershell file. Use the "`" (backtick) key to separate lines. e.g.:

```
PS > Write-Host `
>>> hello, world!
```

So you could do

```
PS > Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { `
>>>    Write-Host $_ `
>>>    doFoo() `
>>>    doBar() `
>>> ` }
```

Comment: Note that backticks are only required to continue a single command, as in the first example of putting the arguments to `Write-Host` on a separate line. When a line ends with an open expression (i.e. open bracket `{`, open parenthesis `(`, pipe `|`, operator `+`, `-`, ...), the interpreter will automatically wait for more input. The second example will execute the same without any backticks.

Answer (score 7):

Basically you want to execute 2 commands in `ForEach-Object` statement, right?
Just use `;` to separate commands in this way `ForEach-Object { command1; command2 }`

In your code it should be something like this

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_; Write-Host $_ }
```